# Reorganise Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I cannot seem to figure out a performant algorithm (using numpy) to reorganise the following arrays. I have a long explicite `vectors` array, which I want to reorganise into a `vertices` array, that has all the unique points in it and an `indices` array that is a placeholder to rebuild the `vectors` with the indices of the `vertices` array. I need an algorithm that goes both ways.

The following example might explain it. This goes in:

```
vectors (Nx3x3):
[[[a.x, a.y, a.z], [b.x, b.y, b.z], [c.x, c.y, c.z]],
 [[ .... c .... ], [ .... d .... ], [ .... a .... ]],
 [[ .... b .... ], [ .... d .... ], [ .... e .... ]],...]
```

And I want these to come out:

```
vertices (Nx3):
[[a.x, a.y, a.z],
 [b.x, b.y, b.z],
 [c.x, c.y, c.z],
 [ .... d .... ],...]

indices (Nx3):
[[0, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 4],..]
```

The other way around is already working for me.

The letters are actually floats, but for easier understanding I replaced them.

I need this to load a Mesh with [numpy-stl](https://numpy-stl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stl.html#module-stl.mesh) and restructure it to fit another datatype. My current implementation looks something like this:

```py
# from vector to vertices and indices
help1 = vectors.reshape([int(m.vectors.size/3), 3])
_, indices, inverse = np.unique(help1, axis=0, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
vertices = help1[np.sort(indices)] # this gives what I want
faces = np.zeros(help1.shape[0], dtype=int)

# this is super slow and trivial, but it gives the correct result...
for i, h1 in enumerate(help1):
    for j, v1 in enumerate(vertices):
        if np.array_equal(h1, v1):
            faces[i] = j
faces = faces.reshape(int(faces.shape[0]/3), 3)
```

The other way is already working, but just for clarification, here it is:

```
# from vertices and indices to vector
m = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(len(faces), dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))

for i, face in enumerate(faces):
    for j in range(3)
        m.vectors[i,j] = vertices[face[f],:]
```

The thing is, that `numpy.unique` sorts the `vertices` array, which makes things out of order. But I cannot use `panda.unique` (I think) because it wouldnt work with `numpy-stl`.

Thanks for your help.